# How to change my experience order in SO Career?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have updated all my work experience in random order (https://careers.stackoverflow.com/sriraman). Now, I want to sort it based on joining date. What should I do to achieve it?

I know a way to do it. I have to delete all my experience and add it again. Is there any other way to do it?

**Update :**

Just now I found that this feature is available. But, the icon is just not visible. I have attached the screenshot below. Please fix it asap. So, Users can use this sorting feature.

[image]

Comment: This certainly *used* to exist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242675/248731

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. As you point out we weren't quite displaying those arrows.

I've pushed a fix and they should be back now.

Thanks for the report.